# Problems with uploading point coordinate British National Grid data into QGIS as .csv file

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, csv

I'm very much hoping someone can help me with this, please. I have uploaded raster data from Digimap to use for maps for field sites for my research in the UK. The issue is that this map data use British National Grid coordinates (i.e OSGB36/British National Grid (EPSG:27700 I believe)) rather than, say, Lat/Long coordinates. This originally confused me as I was trying to upload point coordinate data that were lat/long rather than British National Grid (I didn't check this until earlier today, I just assumed they were lat/long for some reason). Unfortunately, even after converting the coordinates in the .csv file, I still cannot upload them as point coordinate data into QGIS, instead they come out as faulty/seemingly useless attribute tables.

Here are my data that I have been trying to upload, on a .csv file:

[image]

Here is the menu that I have been using to try to upload the data, but I'm not sure what to select, considering the fact that I just have one column of values (i.e the National Grid values):

[image]

Please, please let me know if there is any way I can upload these point coordinates as National Grid coordinates, rather than having to change my maps (which would present other issues, unfortunately, mostly due to liscensing constraints).

Comment: Please post a link to your data or at least a few complete lines in text format. Not a photo.

Comment: https://we.tl/t-kviNXesoC2

Comment: Best I can figure, #6, NS663140 becomes Easting,Northing:266300,614000 and Longitude,Latitude:55.401657 ,-4.1128909. Check out these 2 websites: https://gridreferencefinder.com/ and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTTcMqsJ4CY.

Answer (score 1):

The "NT 9791" format would be a 1km x 1km square. You can download shapefiles here: https://github.com/charlesroper/OSGB_Grids/find/master
As for the 6-digit number, I don't know.
[image]